# Change SQL Server 2008 name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to change my SQL Server's name.

Currently I am connecting to `SERVER1\SQLSERVER`. `SERVER1` is the machine name. I want to change it so I could connect to `SERVER2\SQLSERVER` and keep `SERVER1` as the machine name.

I tried:

```
sp_dropserver 'SERVER1\SQLSERVER'
sp_addserver 'SERVER2\SQLSERVER', local
```

Then I restarted the server.

If I verify I get the new server name:

```
select @@servername
```

Looks like the name was changed but i cant connect to `SERVER2\SQLSERVER` while the `SERVER1\SQLSERVER` connection still works.

What am I missing here ... and is this even possible?

Comment: Is your DNS server working? Server1 should be your current name and should be translated to something like: "domain server name + IP | current server name +  IP".

Comment: Well, according to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) it should work. Now see if there's any exception or error that you need to check.

Comment: its a virtual and the network is disabled. I only change sql server name and not machine name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't changing the physical server's name you'll need to change the name that SQL Server knows back.

```
sp_dropserver 'SERVER2\SQLSERVER'
sp_addserver 'SERVER1\SQLSERVER', local
```

You then just need to put an alias in DNS so that when people try to connect to SERVER2 then are redirected to SERVER1 without knowing about it.  Specifically you'll want (or you'll want your sysadmin) to put a CNAME record into DNS pointing SERVER2 to SERVER1.